# Cleartop not works for Activity with noHistory=true

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Hi i am having a LoginActivity which is defined as noHistory=true. When the user is authorised  properly he ll diverted to the MainActivity of my app. When the user selects logout from main activity i m launching an intent to the Loginactivity with FLAG_ACTIVTY_CLEAR_TOP. But when i press back from LoginActivity now it takes me back to the MainActivity.

see my code

```
logoutBotton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            showLogoutDialog();
        }
    });

private void showLogoutDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Logout");
    dialog.setMessage("Do you really want to logout?");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Logout", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);        
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

For your kind reference LoginActivity is having noHistory=true. Help me what is going wrong in my code. I want to close the app when back pressed from LoginActivity.

Comment: You said you are using  FLAG_ACTIVTY_CLEAR_TOP, but in code, I didn't see that flag... and also make sure to dismiss the Dialog before starting another Activity...

Comment: Sorry that was just a change in my code and i copied it as it is. Now i edited the actual code to.

Comment: You can finish the MainActivity after starting LoginActivity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use some sort of global variables to keep track of whether the user had logged in or not. something like this,

```
public boolean loggedIn = false;
```

and then in mainActivity, override `onResume()` and `finish()` if you're logged out:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  if (!loggedIn)
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

follow below steps:-
it worked for me

1)make  `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` for your login activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

2) use for finishing activity

```
intent = new Intent(activity, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

it is working for me

Comment: okay going step by step have you true android:clearTaskOnLaunch..?

Answer (score 0):

Why to maintain flags? You ca simply finish Activity when user clicks on Logout...

```
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Logout",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
```